# Python empty counter comparison

Tags: python

Does anyone know why the following is `False` not `True`? Isn't counters supposed to be similar to multisets? Any references to docs welcome.

```
Counter()==Counter({'a': 0})
```

Comment: Why should it be `True`? There is a datapoint in the other `Counter`.

Comment: The docs say they are supposed to be similar to multisets, in that context this is true.

Comment: Similar does not mean they are the same thing. `Counter` object also support non-integer values, for example.

Comment: The second `Counter` tells you that `'a'` was counted and found to be zero.  Or perhaps that `'a'` previously was counted but is now zero.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [`Counter` documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

> **Note**: Counters were primarily designed to work with positive integers to represent running counts; however, care was taken to not unnecessarily preclude use cases needing other types or negative values.

As such they are *not exactly* like multi-sets; they *explicitly* support values beyond just positive integers, and any keys set to `0` are still considered datapoints.

You can explicitly remove any counters at or below 0 by subtracting an empty `Counter` object:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter({'a': 0}) - Counter()
Counter()
>>> Counter({'a': 0, 'b': 1, 'c': -1}) - Counter()
Counter({'b': 1})
```

Comment: `Counter({'a': 0, 'b': 1}) - Counter()` is pretty cool but also not intuitive.  (This is not a criticism of your answer.)

Comment: @StevenRumbalski: It's a method to explicitly remove any counts set to 0, at least. A work-around, granted.

Answer (score 5):

While `Counter` can be used to model multisets, in which case you might expect the two values to be equal, the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html) say:

> The multiset methods are designed only for use cases with positive values. The inputs may be negative or zero, but only outputs with positive values are created.

Since you used a zero count, it no longer works exactly as a multiset. Since `Counter` is a subclass of `dict`, `Counter()` and `Counter({'a': 0})` will be treated as different.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, I'll accept this answer once the timer elapses. [edit] can't accept two answers :(, I'll vote this up instead.