# How to smartly annihilate an item of an Counter object when its count reduced to zero?

Tags: python, counter

I conjured up with a dumb solution: `a['a'] -= 1;if a['a'] == 0: del a['a']`.

Then I saw a smarter solution: `a -= Counter(['a'])` from [Python empty counter comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21859254/12080580).

So are there any other better ways?

Comment: With `+a` you can create a new Counter without nonpositive elements. Less writing but also less efficient.

Comment: @MichaelButscher Well, this is a amazing way to copy a Counter too.